# Clear inputs when a button is clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I need to have this feature, when the cancel button is clicked, all the previous inputs shall be cleared. I mean, if the value in the textfield or scroll-bar should be reset to default. This is how I got now, the value still exists even when I click the cancel button (`<button type="delete" onClick={deleteFilter} >X</button>`) although the filter is disabled:

```
const [stateSelected, setStateSelected] = useState('')
    const [jobType, setJobType] = useState('');
    const [type, setType] = useState('');
    var states = statepicker.getStates('us');
    document.body.style = 'position:absolute;';

    const stateChange = e => {
        setStateSelected(e.target.value)
    }

    const jobChange = e => {
        setJobType(e.target.value)
    }

    const typeChange = e => {
        setType(e.target.value)
    }

    function filterOn(){
        if(filter.position != "" || filter.state != "" || filter.type != ""){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function deleteFilter(){
        setFilter({
            position: "",
            state: "",
            type: ""
        })
    }

    const handleSignUp = useCallback(async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        
        setFilter({
            position: jobType,
            state: stateSelected,
            type: type
        });
        setFilterOpen(false);
        setJob([]);
    })

    return (
        <div>
                <div className="settings__Section">
                    <div className="settings__SectionHeader">
                        Filter
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
                        <input className="settings__inputBox" name="occupation" type="occupation" placeholder="Job Title" onChange={jobChange}/>

                        <select className="settings__inputSelect" onChange={stateChange} value={stateSelected}>
                        <option value={""} disabled={true}>Select State</option>
                        {
                            states.map(state => (
                                <option value={state} name="state">{state}</option>
                            ))
                        }
                        </select>

                        <select className="settings__inputSelect" onChange={typeChange} value={type}>
                            <option value={""} disabled={true}>Select Job Type</option>
                            <option value={"Entry Level"} name="type">Entry Level</option>
                            <option value={"Internship"} name="type">Internship</option>
                            <option value={"Fellowship"} name="type">Fellowship</option>
                            <option value={"Apprenticeship"} name="type">Apprenticeship</option>
                        </select>

                        <button type="submit" className="settings__signBtn">Save Filter</button>
                        
                    </form>

                    {filterOn() && 
                        <div>
                            <p>Position: {filter.position} Location: {filter.state} Job Type: {filter.type}</p>
                            <button type="delete" onClick={deleteFilter} >X</button>
                        </div>
                    }
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Where is setFilter defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
                        <input className="settings__inputBox" name="occupation" type="occupation" placeholder="Job Title" onChange={jobChange}/>

                        <select className="settings__inputSelect" onChange={stateChange} value={stateSelected}>
                        <option value={""} disabled={true}>Select State</option>
                        {
                            states.map(state => (
                                <option value={state} name="state">{state}</option>
                            ))
                        }
                        </select>


                        <button type="submit" className="settings__signBtn">Save Filter</button>
                        <button type="reset" >X</button>
                    </form>
```

Try with reset button it does the thing here I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Ok, although there is some lines missing in your code i think i know what the problem is.
The filter renders if either position, state, or type is different from empty string.

But when you delete the filter you are only resetting position and state:

```
function deleteFilter(){
    setFilter({
        position: "",
        state: ""
    })
}
```

So to fix it, just add type to this state function being called:

```
  function deleteFilter () {
    setFilter({
      position: '',
      state: '',
      type: ''
    })
  }
```

Comment: Well, you don't. That's my fault to be honest. I tried to make my code secret and delete something but it doesn't help at all. I put my entire code up, please have a look again!